# Enabling audit rules in falco

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, sysdig, falco

I  had installed falco using helm in my minikube cluster(v1.22.0 kubernetes v1.17.17). The falco is working good and showing logs for default rules in falco-rules.yaml but when it comes comes to k8s audit rules, it doesn't show any logs even on doing something violating the rules. Can you help with how to enable k8s rules in falco?

Answer (score 0):

Error fixed by enabling dynamic auditing feature in minikube.